# Crawler for Twitter social graph via python

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

I am sorry for asking but I am new in writing crawler.

I would like to crawl Twitter space for Twitter users and follow relationship among them using python.

Any recommendation for starting points such as tutorials?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

besides reading the twitter api?

a good starting point would be the great [python twitter library](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) by mike verdona which personally I think is the the best one. (also an [intorduction](http://weblog.becomingguru.com/2009/05/awesome-python-twitter-library-see.html) here)

also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577399/python-twitter-library-which-one) in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of Tweepy myself - https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

You'll have to refer to the [Twitter docs for the API methods](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) that you're going to need. As far as I know, Tweepy wraps all of them, but I recommend looking at Twitter's own docs to find out which ones you need.

To construct a following/follower graph, you're going to need some of these:

- [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids) - grab followers (in IDs) for a user
- [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) - grab followings (in IDs) for a user
- [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) - grab up to 100 users, specified by IDs